# Using extratorrent.cc

Tags: help, bittorrent

I am having trouble loading all the content at extratorrent.cc. I get past the Captcha fine, then the page loads but with none of the torrent content. And searching for a torrent file doesn't work either. I just have a consistent blank white space in the page. I have temporarily allowed scripts in the torbrowser toolbar and tried changing identity too.

This has been an issue for me for a few weeks now. Very occassionaly the site 'works' but then goes back to the same problem described.

Comment: Looks like it's their site that's broken.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that exit nodes that are used are mostly blocked, I had this situation when I was trying to use a webmail - it said that sending is impossible because of spam listing of the client IP. In this case nothing than "try and change exit" will work, I'm afraid. Also take a look at network activity tab or install Firebug - sometimes some in-JS requests are failing silently, and that's why it can be broken.

Comment: How do you know they're blocked?

Comment: from the words of the question. It seems like exact situation I solved.